# types of nodes in DOM

Tags: html, xml, dom

I am reading the book "Dom Scripting" by Jeremy Keith. I read that there are total 12 types of nodes in DOM. I am just aware of five of them which are -

```
Document
Element
Text
Attribute
Comment
```

I don't know about any other node. Please provide me with the knowledge that I don't have.

Comment: See: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp (w3schools is not considered a good reference normally, but it was the first Google hit [btw., did you not try googling it? -1] and it lists the node types in a short overview.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDL for the `Node` interface from the [DOM Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Core-20030226/DOM3-Core.html#core-ID-1950641247):

```
interface Node {

    // NodeType
    const unsigned short      ELEMENT_NODE                   = 1;
    const unsigned short      ATTRIBUTE_NODE                 = 2;
    const unsigned short      TEXT_NODE                      = 3;
    const unsigned short      CDATA_SECTION_NODE             = 4;
    const unsigned short      ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE          = 5;
    const unsigned short      ENTITY_NODE                    = 6;
    const unsigned short      PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE    = 7;
    const unsigned short      COMMENT_NODE                   = 8;
    const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_NODE                  = 9;
    const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE             = 10;
    const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE         = 11;
    const unsigned short      NOTATION_NODE                  = 12;
    // ...
}
```

The number is useful when you have a reference to a node and need to know what type it is (not all browsers support the constants):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("example");
console.log(elem.nodeType); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `for(key in Node) console.log(key, ' = ' + Node[key])` in your browser console will print all the supported node types and their numeric values.